# How to point subdomain to aws ec2

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I have created sub domain of my site.
Its on bigrocks.
Now I have ec2 instance with elastic ip and I am running a site from there.
I can access that site by IP/SITE_NAME from local browsers of current machines also. SO it runs on ec2 as well as on current machine.
Now I want to link that site to my su bdomain.
So how can I do that?
I don't want to redirect sub domain.
Browser should display the sub domain name it self and contents from aws ec2 instance
Please help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Login to your cpanel.
go to simple DNS Zone Editor

Enter your sub domain name and IP address of aws ec2 instance in A records and click on Add.

Now you can open your subdomain/site_name and you wil see the page which is hosted on aws ec2 instance.

Comment: how long does it take for the domain to show the website?

Answer (score 5):

Create an A record for your subdomain, using the Elastic IP as the value.